# Why don't some objects have a constructor in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, object, constructor

The JavaScript code below has a different effect in different browsers:

```
document.write(this.location.constructor);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(this.constructor);
document.write("<br/>");
```

In Chrome, the page has:

```
function Location() { [native code] }
function DOMWindow() { [native code] }
```

In Firefox, the page has:

```
[object Location]
[object Window]
```

In IE8, the page has:

```
undefined
undefined
```

The difference between Chrome and Firefox might be different `toString()` implementations. I just cannot understand why the two objects' constructors are ***undefined*** in IE. If their constructors are undefined, what about their prototypes? Are they also ***undefined***?

Answer (score 1):

Using the IE8 debugging console, I have no problems using the code you gave as an example.

My results...

```
[object Location]
[object Window]
```

Are you sure that something else is not causing these to fail?

Comment: I'm using IE 8.0.6001.18372. 
Interestingly, if I load one local html with "document.write(this.constructor)", it is undefined; if I just type "javascript:this.constructor" in URL input bar, it shows [object Window].